# How to dynamiclly set the grid.column/row of a UserControl in a view build by ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm trying to view a ObservableCollection containing my own class type "NodViewModel" in a UserControl. The UserControl has row and column -definitions and what I want to do is to dynamiclly set the Grid.Column and Row -property for each NodViewModel as a NodView (also a usercontrol). Like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestarDataBinding.Views.KlassView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:m="clr-namespace:TestarDataBinding.Models"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestarDataBinding.ViewModels"
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:TestarDataBinding.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="110" Width="110"
         >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    ---"Foreach in ObservableCollection<NodViewModel>"---
        <v:NodView DataContext="{Binding NodModel}" 
                    Grid.Column="{Binding Position.Column}"
                    Grid.Row="{Binding Position.Row}" />
    ---"endforeach"---
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not include your Column & Row with each NodViewModel and then use the ItemsControl to iterate through your ObservableCollection<NodViewModel>

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that if you need to generate your columns & rows dynamically, I've used something similar to what's described in this article: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding NodKlassRepository}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodTemplate}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding NodKlassModel.Row}"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding NodKlassModel.Column}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

And in the NodTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NodTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:NodKlassViewModel}">
        <v:NodKlassView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Itemscontrol and bind your ObservableCollection to itemsource of that itemscontrol

Comment: Thank you Hasan, though I've tried to use itemscontrol but it wont set the column or row property, no mather how I do...